# Better way of adding data.frame columns by referring to indeces

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe, addition

This question seems basic but I have not been able to find an answer to it.

I want to add columns of a `data.frame` together by just referring to their indeces.

Suppose I want to add columns 1,2, and 4.

```
df <- data.frame(
  a=rep(1, 5),
  b=rep(2, 5),
  c=rep(3, 5),
  d=rep(4, 5)
)
```

I know that explicitly referring to the column names I can do

```
> df$a + df$b + df$d
[1] 7 7 7 7 7
```

And referring to indeces I can do

```
> df[1] + df[2] + df[4]
  a
1 7
2 7
3 7
4 7
5 7
```

However, the index option above requires me to write out the name of the `data.frame` for every column I want to add.

Is there a way to add these columns together while just referring to the indeces and the `data.frame` once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the rowSums function and refer to columns by setting a vector of column numbers in `df[, ]`.

```
rowSums(df[, c(1,2,4)]
[1] 7 7 7 7 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Or within a `data.table`:

```
dt[, sum := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = c(1, 2, 4)]
dt[, sum := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = c('a', 'b', 'd')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with(df, a + b + d)
[1] 7 7 7 7 7
```

Comment: Although not appropriate for my current problem this is good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)  # Load package
dt <- data.table(df) # Convert to data.table
dt[, a + b + d]      # Sum columns
[1] 7 7 7 7 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is

```
Reduce(`+`, df[-3])
#[1] 7 7 7 7 7
```

Or  a variant of @PierreLafortune

```
df$a + df$b + df$d
#[1] 7 7 7 7 7
```

Comment: I like the `Reduce` approach because I'm not limited to addition. I can do `/` and `*` as well. I'm not sure I understand how this function works though. When I do `Reduce(sum, df[-3])` I get 35 but when I do `Reduce(max, df[-3])` I get 4.

Comment: @Warner  There are some functions you can use with `Reduce` and `sum` will get the whole sum instead of rowwise `sum`.

Comment: akrun do you know of a function, most likely from a package, that works like `Reduce()` but is faster? I am using `Reduce` to merge a list of several hundred dataframes like this `Reduce(function(x,y) {full_join(x,y)}, masterlist)` . I know this is a little off topic but it might but nice to have an alternative that works like `Reduce` for arithmetic operations.

Comment: @Warner I think there is `reduce` function in one of the hadleyverse packages though not sure.