# Calculate rowMeans on a range of column (Variable number)

Tags: r, rowsum

I want to calculate rowMeans of a range of column but I cannot give the hard-coded value for colnames (e.g c(C1,C3)) or range (e.g. C1:C3) as both names and range are variable. My df looks like:

```
> df
  chr name age  MGW.1 MGW.2  MGW.3 HEL.1 HEL.2 HEL.3
1 123  abc  12  10.00    19  18.00    12 13.00   -14
2 234  bvf  24 -13.29    13  -3.02    12 -0.12    24
3 376  bxc  17  -6.95    10 -18.00    15  4.00    -4
```

This is just a sample, in reality I have columns ranging in MGW.1 ... MGW.196 and so. Here Instead of giving the exact colnames or an exact range I want to pass initial of colnames and want to get average of all columns having that initials. Something like: `MGW=rowMeans(df[,MGW.*]), HEL=rowMeans(df[,HEL.*])`

So my final output should look like:

```
> df
      chr name age  MGW      Hel
    1 123  abc  12  10.00    19
    2 234  bvf  24  13.29    13
    3 376  bxc  17  -6.95    10
```

I know these values are not correct but it is just to give you and idea. **Secondly I want to remove all those rows from data frame which contains NA in the entire row except the first 3 values**.

Here is the dput for sample example:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(chr = c(123L, 234L, 376L), name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("abc", 
"bvf", "bxc"), class = "factor"), age = c(12L, 24L, 17L), MGW.1 = c(10, 
-13.29, -6.95), MGW.2 = c(19L, 13L, 10L), MGW.3 = c(18, -3.02, 
-18), HEL.1 = c(12L, 12L, 15L), HEL.2 = c(13, -0.12, 4), HEL.3 = c(-14L, 
24L, -4L)), .Names = c("chr", "name", "age", "MGW.1", "MGW.2", 
"MGW.3", "HEL.1", "HEL.2", "HEL.3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: I asked a related question yesterday and the answers might help you out. Here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38594808/better-way-of-adding-data-frame-columns-by-referring-to-indeces

Comment: @Warner As I mentioned in my question, I cannot explicitly mention the colnames or indices, because they are variable, sometimes there will be 196 columns for which I want a rowMean and sometimes there will be 198 or so.

Comment: You can subset `df` with a "logical" vector of positions where `names(df)` `?startsWith` `"MGW"` etc. Also, see, `?complete.cases` to find rows that contain only `NA` (after subsetting all but first three columns).

Comment: Can you hardcode the colnames prefix (`MGW.*`, `HEL.*`) ? Or do you need to regroup them programmatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea achieving your desired output without hardcoding variable names:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  # remove rows where all values are NA except the first 3 columns
  filter(rowSums(is.na(.[4:length(.)])) != length(.) - 3) %>%
  # gather the data in a tidy format
  gather(key, value, -(chr:age)) %>%
  # separate the key column into label and num allowing 
  # to regroup by variables without hardcoding them
  separate(key, into = c("label", "num")) %>%
  group_by(chr, name, age, label) %>%
  # calculate the mean
  summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  spread(label, mean)
```

---

I took the liberty to modify your initial data to show how the logic would fit special cases. For example, here we have a row (#4) where all values but the first 3 columns are `NA`s (according to your requirements, this row should be removed) and one where there is a mix of `NA`s and values (#5). In this case, I assumed we would like to have a result for `MGW` since there is a value at `MGW.1`:

```
#  chr name age  MGW.1 MGW.2  MGW.3 HEL.1 HEL.2 HEL.3
#1 123  abc  12  10.00    19  18.00    12 13.00   -14
#2 234  bvf  24 -13.29    13  -3.02    12 -0.12    24
#3 376  bxc  17  -6.95    10 -18.00    15  4.00    -4
#4 999  zzz  21     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA
#5 888  aaa  12  10.00    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
#Groups: chr, name, age [4]
#
#    chr   name   age       HEL       MGW
#* <int> <fctr> <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1   123    abc    12  3.666667 15.666667
#2   234    bvf    24 11.960000 -1.103333
#3   376    bxc    17  5.000000 -4.983333
#4   888    aaa    12       NaN 10.000000
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(chr = c(123L, 234L, 376L, 999L, 888L), name = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("aaa", "abc", "bvf", "bxc", "zzz"
), class = "factor"), age = c(12L, 24L, 17L, 21L, 12L), MGW.1 = c(10, 
-13.29, -6.95, NA, 10), MGW.2 = c(19L, 13L, 10L, NA, NA), MGW.3 = c(18, 
-3.02, -18, NA, NA), HEL.1 = c(12L, 12L, 15L, NA, NA), HEL.2 = c(13, 
-0.12, 4, NA, NA), HEL.3 = c(-14L, 24L, -4L, NA, NA)), .Names = c("chr", 
"name", "age", "MGW.1", "MGW.2", "MGW.3", "HEL.1", "HEL.2", "HEL.3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Answer (score 3):

**Firstly**

I think you are looking for this to get mean of rows:

```
df$mean.Hel <- rowMeans(df[, grep("^HEL.", names(df))])
```

And to delete the columns afterwards:

```
df[, grep("^HEL.", names(df))] <- NULL
```

**Secondly**

To delete rows which have only `NA` after the first three elements.

```
rows.delete <- which(rowSums(!is.na(df)[,4:ncol(df)]) == 0)
df <- df[!(1:nrow(df) %in% rows.delete),]
```

Comment: This will append a new columns Hel.mean I want to delete the individual column from df as well, please refer to my desired output mention above.

Comment: Added a line to delete the columns.

Comment: What do you mean by Secondly... ?? .. I think you are saying that repeat it for MGW and so on all the columns you want, right ?

Comment: "I want to remove all those rows from data frame which contains NA in the entire row except the first 3 values." I was just going to post a solution to that but it had some problems.

Comment: Can you guide me how can I append one more column in df which contains SD of the entire row. I tried to follow [ŧhis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861734/calculating-standard-deviation-of-each-row) but it is not working for me.

Comment: I am trying this `> rowSds_R <- function(x, na.rm=T) {
+     suppressWarnings({
+         apply(x, MARGIN=1L, FUN=sd, na.rm=T)
+     })
+ }
> df$HelT.SD <- rowSds_R(df[, grep("^HelT.", names(df))])` and I think it is working.

Comment: Maybe better to open a new question for this if you don't find solution...